# Parallel programming over multiple machines without clustering

Tags: parallel-processing, neural-network

I'm going to be a college student at 40.  I'll be studying IT and plan on doing a bachelor's project.  The basic idea is to try to use neural nets to evaluate bias in media.  The training data will be political blogs with well known biases.

What I need is a programming language that can run parallel on multiple machines that are networked, but not clustered.  I have 2 Linux machines and 3 running OS X.  I would prefer if the language would compile to binary rather than bytecode or to a VM, but I'll take what I can get.  I don't need any GUI libraries, so that's not a constraint.  I do most of my programming in python, but I'm willing to learn another language if it'll make the parallel execution easier.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you expect processing to be the bottleneck? Are you sure that disk or network I/O isn't more important for you? I would make really sure that I need the extra power, before investing all the time and energy.

Comment: I don't particularly think processing is the bottleneck.  The experiments I've done with neural networking so far have required lots of computational time.  I'd like to cut that time down a bit.  But I agree that disk I/O is a serious bottleneck.  My network is fast enough (gigabit).

Comment: The reason I asked is that implementing distributed algorithms is *hard*. It will probably be easier for you to speed up your program on a single machine than to implement a distributed version correctly. You might also want to consider using an existing implementation of neural nets. Implementing *and* applying a non-trivial program seems like a large bachelor's project to me.

Comment: Thanks Jørgen.  You're probably right.   I'll take it over with my advisor next time I see him.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you consider sticking with Python.  Learning a new language, at the same time as you start tackling parallel / distributed computing, may well throw a spanner in your works that you just don't need.  I believe that your time will be better spent tackling the issues of building the neural net you want, rather than learning the peculiarities of a new language.  And, by reputation, Python is eminently suitable for what you plan.  It does, of course, fail your requirement that it should compile to binary but I'm not sure where that is coming from.

When you write *parallel programming over multiple machines without clustering* I'm thinking *oh, he means distributed programming*.  I tend towards the view that parallel computing is a niche within distributed computing, in part defined by the homogeneity (from the programmer's point of view) of the resources used.  This apparent homogeneity is aided tremendously if it is supported by homogeneity of hardware so that there is little gap between vision and reality.

If what you really have is an assortment of computers of different specs and different OSes and communicating over a non-dedicated network then I fear that you will find it difficult building the illusion of homogeneity for the programmer (ie for yourself) and would be better setting out to build a distributed system from the get go.

I just plain disagree with the answer telling you to pick up C and MPI, I think you'll make progress much faster much quicker with Python.

Good luck with your studies.

Oh, and if you just won't take my advice to forget about a new programming language, consider Haskell and Erlang.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually taking a look at Erlang.  I might take your advice and stick with Python.  I've been using it for years, and it does probably run fast enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like like an interesting project. However thinking laterally wouldn't a GPU based system (ie massively parallel) be more the soupe du jour? Hence something like C + CUDA perhaps?

I don't know if it's still around but [OCCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam_%28programming_language%29) (from the Transputers of old) was designed to be a parallel system, with it's PAR and SEQ  constructs. I've just read of [this one](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.hensa.ac.uk/parallel/occam/projects/occam-for-all/kroc/)  on linux

Comment: I thought about this, but I'm not sure the GPUs I have are up to the task.  I'd rather not invest in more hardware if I can avoid it.  Especially since I can't upgrade any of the the machines I have.  I'd have to buy a new one or build one from scratch.  (Not entirely out of the question, I guess.)

Comment: And it looks like OCCAM still exists.  The current version is OCCAM-pi.  That led me down the rabbit hole to a list of concurrent programming languages on Wikipedia.  I'll take a look there.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like **C + MPI** to me.